# Feature detection for pausing of Javascript on inactive tabs

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, browser-feature-detection

My webapp opens a popup window and then, after an AJAX request in the main window, it updates the URL of the popup window.

As I found out, on iOS devices, Javascript doesn't run in the main window when it's in the background (because the popup opened).

This seems to be a reasonable decision for the engineers who designed the mobile Safari to conserve battery power, so I can imagine other devices out there doing the same. (Are there?)

Now I could open the popup URL in the main window instead. However, since this provides worse user experience for browsers that can run Javascript in the background, I would like to detect this behavior beforehand. What would be the best way to do that?